# Proper way of passing additional view data to EditorFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

If I pass view data like this

```
@(Html.EditorFor(x => x.User2, "GenericList", 
     new ViewDataDictionary { 
         { "ListType", ListType.CustomValidation }, 
         { "Param1", ObjectType.Asset }, 
         { "Param2", "User2" }, 
         { "DefaultValue", Model.User2 } 
      }
 ))
```

I am unable to access the Values via ViewData["ListType"]. The keys are stored in a property called Keys, and the values are stored in a ICollection property called Values

Passing the ViewData this way

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.User2, "GenericList", 
    new { ListType = ListType.CustomValidation, 
          Param1 = ObjectType.Asset, 
          Param2 = "User2", 
          DefaultValue = Model.User2 
    }
 )
```

means I can get the values easily like ViewData["ListType"].

I don't liek the 2nd method of doing things because it's using anonymous types instead of a ViewDataDictionary. How can I use the first method but still call the ViewData as I expect to be,

Comment: The is no overload of `EditorFor()` that accepts a `ViewDataDictionary` dictionary for the `additionalViewData` (it has to be an `object` whse values are merged with the models `ViewDataDictionary`. You could create your own extension method if you really want to do this.

Comment: Don't do it. Use attributes for metadata. Use object with properties that describe your View-Model. It is MVC. Use the model